# dc.js x-axis displaying as decimal rather than whole number

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, linegraph

I have a line chart that is the week number on the a-xis and the capacity on the y-axis. However, for some reason the interval for the x-axis is going by 0.5... I want it to go from 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.. rather than 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, etc

[image]

Here is my code for reference

```
let chart = dc.lineChart("#chart");
let ndx = crossfilter(results);
            
let weekDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
     return d.week = +d.week;
});
                
function reduceAdd(p, v) {
    ++p.count;
    p.total += v.capacity;
    p.average = p.total / p.count;
    return p;
}

function reduceRemove(p, v) {
    --p.count;
    p.total -= v.capacity;
    p.average = p.count ? p.total / p.count : 0;
    return p;
}

function reduceInitial() {
    return { count: 0, total: 0, average: 0 };
} 

let capacityGroup = weekDimension.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);
            
chart.width(360)
    .height(200)
    .margins({ top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 30 })
    .mouseZoomable(false)
    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([1, 52]))
    .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
    .brushOn(false)
    .dimension(weekDimension)
    .valueAccessor(function (d) {
        return d.value.average;
    })
    .group(capacityGroup);

dc.renderAll('chart');
```

This is how results would look like

```
{month : "1", capacity: "48"}
{month : "1", capacity: "60"}
{month : "2", capacity: "67"}
{month : "2", capacity: "60"}
{month : "2", capacity: "66"}
{month : "3", capacity: "52"}
{month : "3", capacity: "63"}
{month : "4", capacity: "67"}
{month : "4", capacity: "80"}
{month : "5", capacity: "61"}
{month : "5", capacity: "66"}
{month : "5", capacity: "54"}
```

What do I need to do to ensure my x-axis interval is going by the values in my dataset? I have tried to do `capacityChart.xAxis().tickFormat(d3.format('.0f'));` but that let to the x-axis being 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5..

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, I’m glad to help answer this, but the dc.js axes come straight from D3 so you might have better luck searching without the dc.js tag for this particular question. Or looking at the [d3-axis documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#api-reference) is often sufficient.

Comment: I see, would you suggest that I try to ask another question without the dc tag? I did take try to do tickFormat but that caused my graph to create duplicates..is it because I only have 5 values for the x-axis? I wasn’t having this issue before..

Comment: No problem, I will answer this when I have time. I’m on vacation so it may take a couple days. My point was: if you searched for an answer and didn’t find anything, it is probably because this is not specifically a [dc.js] question. You might try `.ticks()` which affects the number of ticks.

Comment: Gotcha! I will try doing .ticks() as well. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Or `.tickValues()` - I don’t think there is a way to control *how* ticks are chosen - you can specify an approximate number or you can specify the exact ticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to figure to out thanks to Gordon!

I did `capacityChart.xAxis().ticks(maxWeek)` to fix the issue